# "At a slow tempo" vs "in a slow tempo"

Tags: prepositions

Could I say the sentence below? Should I use the preposition "in" instead of "at"?

> I improve day by day but at a slow tempo.

Or, is it totally wrong the whole sentence?

Comment: The whole thing is fine! *Pace* might be a more natural word for *tempo* here, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google ngram viewer shows both "at" and "in" used about equally:
["at a slow tempo", "in a slow tempo"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20a%20slow%20tempo%2C%20in%20a%20slow%20tempo&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20slow%20tempo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20slow%20tempo%3B%2Cc0)

I agree with the comment suggesting "pace", but with "pace" I would use "at", not "in".

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine.  "at" is slightly more common in AmE, but they are equally common in BrE